# shell script to find file type

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am working on a shell script that takes a single command line parameter, a file path (might be relative or absolute). The script should examine that file and print a single line consisting of the phrase:

Windows ASCII

if the files is an ASCII text file with CR/LF line terminators, or

Something else

if the file is binary or ASCII with “Unix” LF line terminators.

currently I have the following code.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
if grep -q "\r\n" $file;then
echo Windows ASCII
else
echo Something else
fi
```

It displays information properly, but when I pass something that is not of Windows ASCII type through such as /bin/cat it still id's it as Windows ASCII. When I pass a .txt file type it displays something else as expected it is just on folders that it displays Windows ASCII.  I think I am not handling it properly, but I am unsure.  Any pointers of how to fix this issue?

Comment: Binary files can contain \r\n as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specify you only need to differentiate between 2 cases, this should work.

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$1"
case $(file "$file") in
  *"ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" )
     echo "Windows ASCII"
  ;;
  * )
     echo "Something else"
  ;;
esac
```

As you have specified `#!/bin/sh`, OR if your goal is total backward compatibility, you may need to change

```
$(file "$file")
```

with

```
`file "$file"`
```

To use your script with filenames that include spaces, note that all `$` variable names are now surrounded with double-quotes. AND you'll also have to quote the space char in the filename when you call the script, i.e.

```
 myFileTester.sh "file w space.txt"
 OR
 myFileTester.sh 'file w space.txt'
 OR
 myFileTester.sh file\ w\ space.txt
 OR
```

---

Also, if you have to start discriminating all the possible cases that `file` can analyze, you'll have a rather large case statement on your hands. AND `file` is notorious for the different messages it returns, depending on the the contents of `/etc/file/magic`, OS, versions, etc.

IHTH

Comment: Actually when I try to pass an ASCII file type .dat for example it displays it as something else, but if I pass file outside of the script it says it is an ASCII type.

Comment: This is what I was mentioning about `/etc/file/magic` messages. You'll have to edit the case statement from `*"ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators"` to `*"Whatever message is being returned from file"`. I hope this is clear. If not, please reply with comment showing exact output of `file yourWindowsASCIIfile.txt`.

Comment: That worked once I had spell things correctly.  By chance how could I handle cases where the name has a space in it?

Comment: See my edits. Basically, all references to $1 and $file are now `"$1` and `"$file"` AND you have to quote the filename when calling it on the command line. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` command to find out file type:

```
$ file /etc/passwd 
/etc/passwd: ASCII English text

$ file /bin/cat 
/bin/cat: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ file test.txt 
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: If I try this 
    if test -f "$file"then
    echo "$file: windows ASCII"
    else
    echo "$file: Bianary"
    fi
Then no matter what file type I pass comes out as ASCII.  Am I missing something here?