# script to convert from ASCII to Unix-style LF

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a script that converts given files from ASCII CR/LF to Unix-style LF.  I am stuck on the if statement of how this would work.  I have it in sudo code but do not know where to go from there.  Can someone point me in the proper direction.

```
!/bin/sh
file=$1
for file in "$@"
do case `file "$file"` in
   *"ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" )
echo ""$file": Windows ASCII"
;;
* )
echo ""$file": Something else"
;;
esac
if file = somethingElse
do
echo converting $filename
convert to unix(I was thinking of using the tr command)
done
```

Comment: `echo ""$file": Windows ASCII"` isn't quoting the way you are intending. That leaves the expansion of `$file` unquoted. You want `echo "$file: Windows ASCII"` probably.

Comment: the ""$file" : Windows ASCII" is that way to handle files with a space in the name.  see my other question for further reasoning as to why I did it this way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963932/shell-script-to-find-file-type

Comment: Your quoting is *exactly* what you *don't* want to handle spaces correctly. You *aren't* quoting the filename expansion so spaces will be evaluated by the shell. Try a file "a____b" (but spaces not _ there) and see what that echo spits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat ctrl-m.txt -vte
ONE ^M$
two ^M$
three$
four$

#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"
do
        if file $file | grep "with CRLF"; then
                echo "$file has CR/LF. Fixing.."
                sed -i 's/^M//g' $file
        fi  
done
```

After running the script against `ctrl-m.txt`:

```
$ ./run.sh ctrl-m.txt 
ctrl-m.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
ctrl-m.txt has CR/LF. Fixing..


$ cat -vet ctrl-m.txt 
ONE $
two $
three$
four$
```

To enter `^M` in the script in vi/vim, you will need to type `CTRL-V` followed by `CTRL-M`. Other editors will have similar means of entering control characters.

Comment: My system does not have dos2unix installed on it. Would my if statement work to do this?

Comment: So I just determined that it is to convert only if it is ASCII Text, with CRLF.  It can be UTF-8 with CRLF.  In order to search for that I would just change what I am greping correct?

Comment: Yes you are right. For e.g `$ cat -evt my-unic.txt 
नमस?M-^M?M-^Mत?M-^G र?M-^Aद?M-^M?M-^Mर?M-^M?M-^Mर मन?M-^M?M-^Mयव?M-^G $
^M$
hello$
$`
`$ file my-unic.txt 
my-unic.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`